# Binary operator + cannot be applied to two int operands

Tags: swift, sum, operands

Hi I have a question about this code:

1)

```
let label = "The width is "
let width = 94
let widthLabel = label + String(width)
```

2)

```
let height = "3"
let number = 4
let hieghtNumber = number + Int(height)
```

The first part is working just fine, but I don't get why the second one is not. I am getting the error 'Binary operator "+" cannot be applied to two int operands', which to me does not make much of sense. Can someone help me with some explanation?

Comment: See also the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40557214/swift-operator-throwing-error-on-two-ints).  Essentially, if A is already declared as a Double of CGFloat or whatever, and B and C are integers, A = B + C will fail with this error message, which obscures the real issue and solution: A = Double(B+C).  This question/answer is at the top of the Google search for this error; in some cases the other question's answer may be more helpful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**1)** The first code works because `String` has an init method that takes an `Int`. Then on the line

```
let widthLabel = label + String(width)
```

You're concatenating the strings, with the `+` operator, to create `widthLabel`.

**2)** Swift error messages can be quite misleading, the actual problem is `Int` doesn't have a `init` method that takes a `String`. In this situation you could use the `toInt` method on `String`. Here's an example:

```
if let h = height.toInt() {
    let heightNumber = number + h
}
```

You should use and `if let` statement to check the `String` can be converted to an `Int` since `toInt` will return `nil` if it fails; force unwrapping in this situation will crash your app. See the following example of what would happen if `height` wasn't convertible to an `Int`:

```
let height = "not a number"

if let h = height.toInt() {
    println(number + h)
} else {
    println("Height wasn't a number")
}

// Prints: Height wasn't a number
```

---

**Swift 2.0 Update:**

`Int` now has an initialiser which takes an `String`, making example 2 (see above):

```
if let h = Int(height) {
    let heightNumber = number + h
}
```

Comment: Does it make any sense to use (Int)someString in any situation. I am just getting confused by the error description that I get that the operands are Int, which means the height is somehow casted to Int.

Comment: No, firstly, that's not the syntax for casting in Swift (you would use a form of `as`, see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html). Secondly, Swift error messages have a habit of being quite misleading, the actual problem is there isn't an `init` on `Int` that takes a `String`.

Comment: I've update my answer with a bit about your first example. If either of the answers solved your problem would you consider marking one as correct?

Comment: Done. Sorry - I didn't do it earlier...I'll have to make an excuse that I am still new :)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is this:

```
let height = "3"
let number = 4
let heightNumber = number + height.toInt()!
```

If you want to get an `Int` from a `String` you use `toInt()`.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But even according to the error description it make sense to be able to perform the operation. It is somehow casting the height to Int.   And I am wondering why is that.

Comment: That's becase you want to initialize an `Int` with a `String` which is not allowed. You can only init `Int` with an integer. For example - `let a = Int(25)`.