# Swift operator "*" throwing error on two Ints

Tags: swift, swift3

I have a very odd error here and i've searched all around and i have tried all the suggestions.  None work.

```
scrollView.contentSize.height = 325 * globals.defaults.integer(forKey: "numCards")
```

> Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to two 'Int' operands

WTF Swift! Why not?  I multiply `Ints` all the time. These *ARE* two `Ints`.  `globals.defaults` is just an instance of `UserDefaults.standard`.  I have tried the following with the same error each time.

```
325 * Int(globals.defaults.integer(forKey: "numCards")   //NOPE

Int(325) * Int(globals.defaults.integer(forKey: "numCards"))  //NOPE

if let h = globals.defaults.integer(forKey: "numCards"){
    325 * h  //NOPE, and 'Initializer for conditional binding must have optional type, not Int'
}

let h = globals.defaults.integer(forKey: "numCards") as! Int
325 * h //NOPE, and 'Forced cast of Int of same type as no affect'

325 * 2 //YES!  But no shit...
```

All of those "attempts" seemed like a waste of time as i know for a fact both of these are `Ints`...and i was correct.  Please advise.  Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The error is misleading. The problem is actually the attempt to assign an `Int` value to a `CGFloat` variable.

This will work:

```
scrollView.contentSize.height = CGFloat(325 * globals.defaults.integer(forKey: "numCards"))
```

The cause of the misleading error (thanks to Daniel Hall in the comments below) is due to the compiler choosing the `*` function that returns a `CGFloat` due to the return value needed. This same function expects two `CGFloat` parameters. Since the two arguments being provided are `Int` instead of `CGFloat`, the compiler provides the misleading error:

> Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to two 'Int' operands

It would be nice if the error was more like:

> Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to two 'Int' operands. Expecting two 'CGFloat' operands.

Comment: Well you are correct.  That does work.  But why in the world does the following work then? `scrollView.contentSize.height = 325 * 2` Is the _misleading error_ a Swift bug?

Comment: The compiler treats number literals differently than variables of a specific type. `325 * 2` can be inferred to be `CGFloat`.

Comment: Ok.  What about your thoughts on the _misleading error_?

Comment: I don't know Swift well enough to understand why it posts such a misleading error in a case like this.

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup The error is because Swift is selecting a version of the \* function that provides the correct return type for the context (in this case, CGFloat). That function is defined as: `public func *(lhs: CGFloat, rhs: CGFloat) -> CGFloat`  That specialized version of the \* function cannot be applied to two Int operands, it requires two CGFloat operands. It's not misleading if you understand that the compiler selected the function specialization based on return type, not arguments.

Comment: @DanielHall So if i understand correctly, using `*` in the context of returning it to a property expecting a `CGFloat`, Swift expects two `CGFloats` to be on either side of the operand?

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup  Exactly

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup  Keep in mind that the function * isn't a single function. There are dozens of versions of it, based on what the types are of the arguments and the return type.  The compiler has to figure out which one of the dozens of functions named "\*" should be used there, and it does so by choosing the version that has the correct return type for where it is being used.

Comment: Someone needs to re-write that error ;)  I would say something more like _Binary operator '* -> CGFloat' cannot be applied ..._  At least that would explain that it's talking about the operator and not the variable types and explain what it's expecting to return.

Comment: @DanielHall  It definitely makes sense now, it's just so poorly written.

Comment: @DanielHall Thanks for the details on the real cause of the error. I summed it up into my answer.

Comment: @rmaddy Nice suggestion on the new error message.  That would be perfect and i could have solved it immediately.

Comment: Actually, now that I read my suggested error again, it may be more confusing. It would lead people to cast each argument to `CGFloat` instead of just casting the result.

Comment: @rmaddy But If you cast each argument to `CGFloat` it would still work, right?  Then the `* -> CGFloat` would have the correct arguments.  I think you're suggested message is much better than the current one at the least.

Comment: Yes, casting both values to `CGFloat` will work. But I think it's better to cast the result and need each argument. As an example, it's more obvious if you have two float values and need an integer result. Better to cast the final float calculation than to cast both floats to integers and do the math on the two integers.

Comment: I had a similar problem with nsDate.addingTimeInterval(30 * 60)
fixed with nsDate.addingTimeInterval(Double(30 * 60))